# How I trigger a Method if I click on a button in asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5, viewbag

I'm new to asp.net mvc 5 and I want to trigger a button do something. Here is my cshtml:

```
...
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-xs btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></span> Räume Anzeigen</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-xs btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></span> Fahrzeuge Anzeigen</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-xs btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></span> Computer Anzeigen</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-xs btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></span> Kontakte Anzeigen</a></td>
                    </tr>
...
```

I used bootstrap. In my Controller I have this method: For Example the first button must do this:

```
public ActionResult Rooms()
{
    DataTable table = getDummyRooms();

    ViewBag.table = table;

    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: use a Url.Action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Url Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx) e.g. this would invoke `MyController` and `Rooms` action method :

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Rooms", "MyController")">Rooms</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Url.Action` in your href.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Rooms","ControllerName")">...</a>
```